# What could cause this ethernet slowdown pattern?

Tags: internet, ethernet, home-networking, gigabit-ethernet

I have a home network (used for teaching, home business, video conferencing and streaming, etc. throughout this year). In July 2020 I had Verizon FIOS installed with 200 Mbps up/down speed and a new gigabit router. Cable ethernet connection to desktop computers a few feet away from the router has always been solidly at the 200+ Mbps level.

However, I've had trouble with the connection to the other side of the apartment: 75 foot ethernet cable to switch, then 20 feet cable to desktop computer there. For the first month it was spotty (I was regularly restarting the switch), then I thought to pull the ethernet cable away from power cables (e.g., A/C unit, power strips) and then it became a solid 200 Mbps to the back room.

But then circa Nov-1 the connection to the back room fell back to sub-100 Mbps and nothing I've done since has let it recover. No hardware changes occurred anywhere around then that I can tell. In particular, any time I test the speed the download has a characteristic falling-off pattern -- starts around 90 Mbps, then in a few seconds trails off down to to 20-30 Mbps or so. Meanwhile, the upload speed is always solidly close to 100 Mbps.

So the internet speed test has now constantly looked like this for the past 1.5 months, no matter what I do:

[image: Speed test results]

What's the most likely diagnosis for this pattern, and what should I try next to fix it?

---

Per suggestions in comments, here's an iperf test between my work (back room) machine and the server connected to the router/modem (front room):

[image: iperf test: 95 Mbps]

Seems like no big surprise there: pretty constant 95 Mbps both ways in that span (so obviously operating at the 100 Mbps protocol). It was the external speed test with its strange, reliable download dropoff that I thought might give extra clues about what I need to replace (esp. since there were no obvious hardware changes when it stopped working at gigabit speeds circa Nov-1).

Any further suggestions?

Comment: Instead of measuring Internet speed, try to connect up a PC/Laptop etc. on each side, and measure LAN speed. (e.g. on Linux, you can use `iperf3`). If LAN speed is fine, my guess for the Internet slowdown would be bufferbloat (google). If LAN speed also decreases, it's time to debug: Swap out parts and change the setup until you've narrowed down possible reasons.

Comment: 94.3 is the theoretical max TCP/IPv4 throughput for 100mbps Ethernet. It is a dead giveaway that your cable has integrity problems on one or both of the pairs that are used for gigabit but not 100mbit Ethernet. But I'd feel better if you were doing local performance measurements with iperf to keep your Internet connection performance out of this.

Comment: @Spiff: Added that, not sure if it gives any other useful information. (?)

Comment: @Spiff Unless there is another Q&A thread that addresses cable damage with regards to speed, I think your comment should be a fuller answer. The reality is answers like this for physical internet connections are usually the culprit. Perhaps a damaged Ethernet port on the modem? Maybe simply unplugging and plugging it back in again can help?